# Localization the Navigation Bar Title in swift

Tags: swift, localization, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I write navigation bar title in Attributes inspector. I would like to translate that title when I switch to other language.

```
 self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Login", comment: "")
```

I write it in override func viewDidLoad().
I took navigation item Object ID "S3Z-Mr-Qda" and translate it in Main.strings file.

```
/* Class = "UINavigationItem"; text = "Package History"; ObjectID = "S3Z-Mr-Qda"; */
```

"S3Z-Mr-Qda.text" = "Login";

However, it does not change at all and how to implement it in swift?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually provide a translation to the title using that method.
The only thing that you did wrong was setting the property "text". As you can see in the code version, a navigationItem has a **title** property instead of **text**.

This would work:

```
"S3Z-Mr-Qda.title" = "Login";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put your translation inside a generic 
`Localizable.strings` file instead of the storyboard translation file.

Then use your same code to load the title text:

```
self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Login", comment: "")
```

Take a look at the official doc in order to create this kind of file:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html

Comment: I will try. Thanks for your answer. :)